# Laravel seeder not working

Tags: php, laravel, seeding

Can anyone see what seems to be the problem with my seeder?

```
public function run()
{
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
    $limit = 30;

    $userId = App\User::all()->lists('id')->toArray();
    $status = App\OrderStatus::all()->lists('id')->toArray();


    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        $chosenUserId = $faker->randomElement($userId);
        $user = App\User::find($chosenUserId);

        DB::table('orders')->insert([
            'created_at' => $faker->date('Y-m-d'),
            'user_id'    => $chosenUserId,
            'status_id'  => $faker->randomElement($status),
            'draft'      => false,
            'address_id' => $user->addresses->first()->id
        ]);
    }
}
```

I keep getting `trying to get property of non-object` error, and I suppose it's because of the last line where I'm attaching `address_id`.

When I take a look at the DB what was created until that point, users and addresses are created fine, and each user has an address assigned to him.

In user model i have:

```
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
addresses -> addresses()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your User model have a function to define the relationship with address model, you should call it as a function not as object attributes:

```
    DB::table('orders')->insert([
        'created_at' => $faker->date('Y-m-d'),
        'user_id'    => $chosenUserId,
        'status_id'  => $faker->randomElement($status),
        'draft'      => false,
        'address_id' => $user->addresses()->first()->id
    ]);
```